# Find and Compare Two Columns Excel (With Screenshots)

Tags: excel, compare, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that will occasionally get new data that I don't know the contents of, I just have to add it to the spreadsheet. Some of the new data is just updating rows that are already in the spreadsheet, and other data is adding new rows. I'm looking for a way to add a column that will tell me if something has changed in the row when I compare the old spreadsheet to the new one.

The sheets have one column that will always have a unique value among all the rows, so I can use that to match rows if the sheets aren't sorted the same way. Here are some screenshots to show what I'm trying to do:

Old Spreadsheet:
[image: Old spreadsheet]

New Spreadsheet:
[image: New spreadshhet]

The only solution I can think of is a large nested IF formula that compares each column one by one, something like:

```
=IF(Old!B2=New!B2,IF(Old!C2=New!C2,"NO","YES"),"YES")
```

The problem with that is that it gets very hard to look at since my actual data is using 33 columns (not including this "Changed?" column) and new columns could be added in the future.

I'm not very technical with Excel, nor have I ever used VBA, so I apologize in advance if there is a simple/obvious solution that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, in the 'New' sheet cell D2 and copied down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Old!A:A,A2)=0,"YES",IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX(Old!A:AG,MATCH(A2,Old!A:A,0),0),LEFT(A2:AG2,254)&"*"))=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2:AG2,LEFT(A2:AG2,254)&"*")),"NO","YES"))
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much. This may be asking too much, but is there a way for it to figure out what column "C" should be if it is always the second to last column? Basically having it automatically change to "D" if one column is added. If not, no biggie, changing three letters is no daunting task.

Comment: It would take some learning, but you could accomplish that with `dynamic named ranges`.  Googling for that term should pop up a lot of results.

Comment: Worked fine for me when I added some sample data in extra columns out to column G.  I'd have to see an example of what's not working for you, and the updated formula you're using.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll look into that further. However, I'm now having an issue when I put the formula into my real data. When I encounter a cell in one of the columns, the formula either returns a #VALUE error, or incorrectly returns FALSE for the IF function. The cell in question is empty both times and on both sheets, but yields different results for different rows. I also have earlier cells that are empty that don't return the #VALUE error. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have updated my answer so that the formula can allow for blanks properly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. I put in your new formula, and the problem still exists, so it has nothing to do with the empty cell, sorry for not doing some more of my own detective work earlier. It looks like the problem is the cell before the empty one has too many characters. I removed some text from the cell, and it works perfectly, however that's not a viable solution since I need the text to remain. The SUMPRODUCT Argument Description says, "2 to 255 arrays..." and I had to limit the cell to 255 characters for it to not return #VALUE. Could this be the problem? Thanks

Comment: yeah, Excel formulas can only handle strings of 255 characters at a time.  More than that will cause issues.  Try using `COUNTIF(A2:C2,LEFT(A2:C2,254)&"*")` for each instance of the `COUNTIF` function.

Comment: Well that's interesting. I just tried doing a `IF(L1=Old!L1, "NO", "YES")` and that worked. Is there a way that I can exclude that column from the range of A:AG? Or would it be easier to just make two formulas, one that has a range of A:K and one of M:AG (where column L is the long text)?

Comment: I have tested it with the LEFT(range,254)&"*" and that is successful on my test data, even with a range going from A:AG and with column L having text longer than 255 characters.  I have edited my answer to the updated formula

Comment: I'll say it again: you're awesome. Thank you so much for all of this.

Answer (score 0):

vlookup would also work well for this problem.

in D2, the formula would be:

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,2,FALSE)=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,3,FALSE)=C2),"NO","YES")
```

The column numbers (2 and 3) are the columns that correspond to the data you are trying to match, using the ID column.

It's possible to find the appropriate column using MATCH if the column names you have match the column names in the old sheet

This would make the formula look more complex, but Excel would adjust the `Old!A:C` reference if more columns are inserted.

The formula would look like this to match against column names

```
=IF(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,MATCH($B$1,Old!$1:$1,0),FALSE)=B2,VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,MATCH($C$1,Old!$1:$1,0),FALSE)=C2),"NO","YES")
```

The difference between this and the last one is the use of `MATCH($B$1,Old!$1:$1,0)` to find the column (using **$**s to anchor the lookup values)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, specialized software for Excel compare is better.

My company use this software. Check it out.

http://www.suntrap-systems.com/ExcelDiff/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQgnWr_RT-8

Comment: I'm not sure what that 1st sentence is suppose to say?

Comment: Not only that, but the formula that tigeravatar created works perfectly, and I've already said that...